# ReactJS (Bootstrap Data Table): Adding edit button with ID's

Tags: reactjs

I started practicing ReactJS-(Laravel/Bootstrap). I have problem regarding adding buttons **(Edit and Delete)** to the column of TableHeaderColumn.

**Problem:** 
The button is not showing to the column

[image: Image Sample]

**Goal:**
To view the mail of user to the other page with the ID.

**State:**

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        unread_mail_api:[]
    }

    this.viewmail = this.viewmail.bind(this);
}
```

**SetState:**

```
axios.get('/api/dashboard').then(response => {
        if(this.mounted)
        {
            this.setState({
                unread_mail_api:response.data[0].mail_unread
            })
        }
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

**Bootstraptable:**

```
<BootstrapTable data={this.state.unread_mail_api} search pagination striped hover version='4'>
    <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id'>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='fullname'>Full Name</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='subject'>Subject</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn  dataField='id' dataFormat={viewmail}>Action</TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

**this Function must be in outside of component:**

```
    function viewmail(cell, row){
    return <Link to={"/view/mail/"+cell} className='btn btn-outline-primary btn lg'>Edit</Link> ;
  }
```

Comment: please provide the content of `unread_mail_api`

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú updated

Comment: Well then, why do you need the `this.state.unread_mail_api.map()` when trying to add the edit and delete buttons? Do the numbers of unread mail affect the numbers of the button?

Comment: i use the unread mail apo.. to get the ID of every user ..

Comment: I dont know if thats good approach to put ID to the a href

Comment: then, please provide your `unread_mail_api` structure. I mean, the `response.data[0].mail_unread` to be exact

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181515/discussion-between-nguyn-thanh-tu-and-devge).